# How to change the `frontend_domain` port in `GRAPHQL_AUTH` in the verification mail?

Tags: reactjs, django, graphql, jwt, graphene-django

I'm working on a Docker-Django-Graphene-React stack where Django is the backend which receive GraphQL queries through Graphene from React which acts as the frontend. Everything runs in docker containers. Django on port 8000 and React on 3000.

I'm currently working on the authentication with the python's `django-graqhql-auth` package.

When a user register itself on the frontend form, the `register` mutation is correctly made to the backend and the account is created.

A mail is sent at the same time to the user's registered mail address containing a verification link with a token that must be used with the `veryifyToken` mutation in order to flag the account as verified.

Here is an example of the link:
`http://localhost:8000/activate/eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IkpvaG5zb2ZuZiIsImFjdGlvbiI6ImFjdGl2YXRpb24ifQ:1mQr0R:Wh25LJ6A1PRVCQT730kXXIk4i2QJgz1a4aNDe7RoZM0`

The problem is that the port on the link is 8000, which redirects to the backend (Django). I would like to redirect the user on port 3000 which is the frontend (React).

According to the [documentation](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/#email_template_variables), I should be able to change the `frontend_domain` which I did. I also changed the `path` and the `protocol` values to see if it works:

Here is what I put in my backend's `settings.py` file:

```py
GRAPHQL_AUTH = {
    "EMAIL_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES": {
        "protocol": "https",
        "frontend_domain": "localhost:3000",
        "path": "verify",
    }
}
```

And I end up with this link:

`https://localhost:8000/verify/eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IkpvaG5zZmdvZmdzbmRmIiwiYWN0aW9uIjoiYWN0aXZhdGlvbiJ9:1mQrIr:2o818drqPP8oVTE4E6fg2F6vMu2zITOjkF96z5K1whY`

The `protocol` and `path` variables were correctly changed but not the `frontend_domain`. The problem is that I cannot redirect the user directly to the frontend.

Is there a way to fix this? Or do I have to create a route on the backend which will redirect the user to the frontend with the token so that I can use the `verifyToken` mutation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be answering this late, but replace `frontend_domain` with `domain` and it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you just have to update to latest version.

```
pip install --upgrade django-graphql-auth
```

Comment: I'm one the latest version, same result. ;/

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you used in protocol: "https" , but should probably be protocol: "http".

I'm in the same project using Django and Graphql Auth and for me worked to send the email to the frontend to Next.js by using protocol: "http".

```
GRAPHQL_AUTH = {
        "EMAIL_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES": {
        "protocol": "http",
        "frontend_domain": "localhost:3000",
        "path": "verify",
      } 
}
```

Comment: Hi, ok got it , thanks for the correction. Will do a proper answer next time !